# How to prevent downloads by directly accessing file via URL?

Tags: php, url, hotlinking

I am making an online streaming website where users can listen to audio or video files. Currently I am calling an mp3 file in an audio tag using below code.

```
<a href="www.domain.com/path-to-audio/file.mp3">Play</a>
```

In my website a user can stream a song but cannot download it. DOWNLOADS ARE PAID. Above code is the worst thing to stream an audio file because when a user copies and pastes the above link on his browser, the song will be downloaded.

How can I securely stream the file without URL download option(user cannot copy the song url and download it).

I am using CodeIgniter(PHP framework), so how can I restrict a user to download the file directly.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040625/play-audio-file-without-downloading-it) question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Something actually relevant; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486191/php-stream-mp3-file / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408927/how-do-i-prevent-direct-access-download-to-mp3-wav-files-while-allowing-a-flash

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `.htaccess` to direct all download requests to your `PHP` Script and not call the real files. Then your script can validate if the user is logged in, only then it will issue a download response. Otherwise even if someone gets the url it won't work for them because the request goes to your PHP Script and file itself is not served automatically

Comment: So you mean to say that instead of direct file link, I redirect it to a PHP page, where it will retrive the songs actual path and send it back?

Comment: I had same question using htaccess is ok, but when the files are stored in CDN then hows the htaccess will function?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Create temporary URLs](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/rackspace-cloud-files-how-to-create-temporary-urls/). You can do similar for your domain as well.